# Reproduce binomial glm using only the model object

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I'm trying to reproduce the results of a binomial `glm` in R.

Consider the data from here http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
```

I can fit the model using:

```
model <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

And, reproduce the model only using the object:

```
model_r <- glm(as.numeric(model$y)~0+model.matrix(model), family = binomial)
cbind(coef(model), coef(model_r))
##                    [,1]        [,2]
## (Intercept) -3.44954840 -3.44954840
## gre          0.00229396  0.00229396
## gpa          0.77701357  0.77701357
## rank        -0.56003139 -0.56003139
```

Now suppose that the column `admit` was the number of success from a number `n` of essays wich is in the column:

```
mydata$n <- 1 + rbinom(n = 400, size = 2, prob = 0.5)
```

Now I have to fit the model using:

```
model <- glm(cbind(admit, n-admit) ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, 
                family = "binomial")
```

How can I reproduce this model just using the model object? I ask this because R keeps only the rate of success in `model$y`.

Comment: What is the purpose for "reproducing" a model?

Comment: Maybe this wasn't the question I should have asked. I need to generate binomial samples using the fitted probabilities, so I was trying to get the `n` used to fit.

Comment: Now with your second approach I can easily get what I want. Thanks

Comment: You can use `model$data$n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reproduce the model in the following way:

```
model_r <- glm(formula(model), model$data, family = family(model))
```

Compare:

```
cbind(coef(model), coef(model_r))
#                     [,1]         [,2]
# (Intercept) -3.693688931 -3.693688931
# gre          0.001855502  0.001855502
# gpa          0.584915067  0.584915067
# rank        -0.450051862 -0.450051862
```

---

Alternatively (similar to your approach):

```
model_r2 <- glm(model.frame(model)[[1]] ~ 0 + model.matrix(model), 
                family = family(model))

cbind(coef(model), coef(model_r2))
#                     [,1]         [,2]
# (Intercept) -3.693688931 -3.693688931
# gre          0.001855502  0.001855502
# gpa          0.584915067  0.584915067
# rank        -0.450051862 -0.450051862
```